# How to generate current year in spring boot properties

Tags: java, spring-boot

In [this](https://www.logicbig.com/tutorials/spring-framework/spring-boot/random-properties.html) article we can see how to generate random properties in `application.properties`. Is there also some way how to generate some other properties like current year using java code in  `application.properties` ?

I tried this:

```
config.current-year=${LocalDate.now.getYear}
```

but it throws exception:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "${LocalDate.now.getYear}"
```

**UPDATE:**

after iamrajshah answer I see random represent class `RandomValuePropertySource` which is loaded in this way:

```
protected void addPropertySources(ConfigurableEnvironment environment,
        ResourceLoader resourceLoader) {
    RandomValuePropertySource.addToEnvironment(environment);
    new Loader(environment, resourceLoader).load();
}
```

so all I need is just to override (Idk now) this function and add there my class which I can use.

Comment: Why not `@ConfigurationProperties` with custom getter?

Answer (score 1):

[You can check this out](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html)
`application.properties` are like registering similar to `*.xml` in previous version of spring.
Spring boot provides `RandomValuePropertySource` which used to generate values.
NOT any other classes supports in this file.

Comment: @hudi Please accept the answer if it has solved your question.

Comment: @iamrajshah From the link, it is not clear how RandomPropertySource will help to generate properties like current year

Comment: @iamrajshah sorry man I can not accepted it. Your answer is good that now I know how 'random' is injected to properties. But there should be way how to to override it and add some my custom properties.

Comment: @hudi ok, I think only random can be given in application.properties, might chance that I am wrong in this.   
if you get any help from answer do upvote!